# Loading data using for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, for-loop, text

I am trying to load data from multiple files. The structure of data file is given by: 
np.double np.double......np.double 
with spaces between each column

I made the proper np.dtype for these files. To load them into different variable, I wrote a for loop to get the path:

```
X = []
run = '001'
for i in range(0, 370, 10):
    X.extend(['Phi_(3)_' + str(i) + '/' + 'SRF_GUN2_PHI(3)' + str(i) + '.Scan.' + run])
```

And then I loaded them manually, like this:

```
Scan_1 = np.loadtxt(open(X[0]), dtype=Scan)
Scan_2 = np.loadtxt(open(X[1]), dtype=Scan) 
Scan_3 = np.loadtxt(open(X[2]), dtype=Scan)
 . . . . 
Scan_36 = np.loadtxt(open(X[35]), dtype=Scan)
```

Is there away to do a for loop for this. Keeping the structure of original files. Or (even better) to combine all these scan files into one big file keeping the format, also using a for loop or anything similar?

Comment: well 1-36 so write a for loop from 1-36 and put the scan files in an array or dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

```
Scans = [np.loadtxt(open(file), dtype=Scan) for file in X]
```

That would create an array of elements 0-36